# Wireless and Bluetooth are not working - Lenovo Y700

Tags: wireless, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo, broadcom

I have an issue trying to enable my wireless card for wifi and bluetooth.
I have been looking on Google some answer but no one can fix this problem.

As far I can see it's a problem with hard block, the problem here is that I don't have a physical button to turn that on. I only have the combination `fn + F5`, but when I press that just *Soft block* changes.

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also I tried to unblock it with `sudo rfkill unblock all` but nothing change

I have tried to add it to the blacklist, but when I do it the only thing that is available is `2: hci0: Bluetooth`

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

This is my network controller

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3831]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Using the command `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` I get this message.

```
[    0.236555] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.669195] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
[    0.669836] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
[    1.747465] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    1.747479] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.747482] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.747484] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.747488] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.798461] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.798475] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.798485] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.798493] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.798502] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.798621] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.803002] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.885325] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    2.100437] nouveau  [  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] using external firmware
[    2.100453] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv117_fuc409c failed with error -2
[    2.100457] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/fuc409c failed with error -2
[    2.274598] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.274600] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.274604] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    2.287465] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.287475] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.287479] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    3.721686] nouveau  [  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] using external firmware
[    3.721695] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv117_fuc409c failed with error -2
[    3.721699] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/fuc409c failed with error -2
```

I Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please edit to add result for `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 1010` thanks

Comment: Hi Jeremy, this is the result
`alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*`

Comment: For the bluetooth please add `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: What kernel are you using? `uname -a` and `lsusb`

Comment: Using `uname -a` I got:
`Linux Mango 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And for `lsusb` :
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0672 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Comment put in other answer by @PaulFrater: "I set up a Linux/Windows dual boot on the exact same machine; however, the above solution does not work for me. The only difference is that I am running Ubuntu-14.04.4, which runs on Linux kernel 4.2.0-30-generic. Any thoughts?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Intel wireless card isn't supported by the kernel you are currently using.  To fix this we can install backports

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make 
sudo make install
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
tar -zxvf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz 
cd iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0/
sudo cp iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

Reboot and wifi should work since you blacklisted `ideapad-laptop` already, if you deleted `ideapad-laptop` from the blacklist, please add it back

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeremy31 my wifi is working, but do you know how can I make it works my bluetooth? 

I just edited my question adding the message from the command that you asked me, because it was too long.

Comment: Bluetooth will need a new kernel download and install [this](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb) so you have firmware for the bluetooth `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily` and reboot, if you have issues you can boot again and hold the SHIFT key so that the GRUB menu appears so you can select Advanced options for Ubuntu then select the 3.19.0 kernel to boot from.